# svg relative to absolute conversion

Tags: svg

I have been developing an application that requires any transformations in an svg to be flattened, and all co-ordinates to be absolute. Its this conversion from relative (or incremental) to absolute that is causing me a problem. The original svg fragment is sourced from an inkscape conversion of a PDF to SVG (and yes it's a pretty ordinay image!). Inkscape has defined the "paths" using relative co-ords. I ran my code to convert to absolute co-ordinates which you would think would be trivial but the files render completely differently. It appears that the start points fot the paths are moved.

I have been searching for an explanation as to why this occurs. I have looked at the converted file I cannot see the problem. The starting point of the paths match in each file match?

Can anyone offer a reason why the conversion does not result in the same result?

The source for the two files are:
Original Relative:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
   
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   viewBox="2420 3960 70 40"
   height="300"
   width="700"
   xml:space="preserve"
   id="svg2436"
   version="1.1">
     
     <g
       
       id="g2446">
         <path
         id="path2616"
         style="fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:none"
         d="m 2440,3992.67 v 6 h -3 l -1,-1 h -2 l -1,-1 -1,-1 -1,-1 -1,-1 h -1 v -1 l -1,-2 -1,-1 v -3 l -1,-1 v -4 l 1,-2 v -1 l 1,-2 v -1 l 1,-1 1,-2 v -1 l 1,-1 1,13 v 3 l 1,1 1,2 h 1 l 1,1 1,1 h 2" /><path
         id="path2618"
         style="fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:none"
         d="m 2453,3976.67 v 1 l -1,1 v 3 l -1,14 -1,-1 -1,-1 -1,-2 -1,-1 v -1 l -1,-1 v -10 l 1,-1 1,-1 v -1 l 1,-1 1,-1 1,-1 1,-1 1,-1" />
         <path
         id="path2620"
         style="fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:none"
         d="m 2477,3994.67 -1,1 -1,1 -1,1 h -2 l -1,1 h -1 l -2,1 h -10 l -1,-1 h -2 l -1,-1 -1,-1 -1,-1 h -1 l 1,-14 v 5 l 1,1 1,1 1,1 v 0 l 1,1 1,1 2,1 h 9 l 1,-1 h 1 l 2,-1 1,-1 1,-1 1,-1 v -2 l 1,-1 v -3" />
         <path
         id="path2622"
         style="fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:none"
         d="m 2482,3982.67 v 3 l -1,2 v 1 l -1,2 v 1 l -1,1 -1,1 -1,1 -1,-13 v -4 l -1,-1 -1,-1 -1,-1 -1,-1 h -1 l -1,-1 -1,-1 h -9 l -2,1 h -1 l -1,1 -1,1 -1,1 -1,1 v -6 h -7 l -1,1 h -2 v 0 l -2,1 h -2 l -1,1 -1,1 h -1 l -1,1 -1,1 -1,1 v 1 l -1,2 v 3 l -1,-13 1,-1 h 1 l 2,-1 1,-1 1,-1 h 2 v 0 l 1,-1 h 3 l 1,-1 h 6 l 2,-1 h 4 2 l 2,1 h 6 l 1,1 h 3 l 1,1 h 2 l 1,1 1,1 1,1 1,1 1,1 1,1 1,1 v 2 l 1,1 v 2 l 1,1 v 2" />
      </g></svg>
```

Same file converted to absolute

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
   
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   viewBox="2420 3960 70 40"
   height="300"
   width="700"
   xml:space="preserve"
   id="svg2436"
   version="1.1">
     
     <g id="g2446">
         <path 
          id="path2616" 
          style="fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:none" 
          d="M2440,3992.67V3998.67H2437L2436,3997.67 H2434L2433,3996.67 2432,3995.67 2431,3994.67 H2430V3993.67L2429,3991.67 2428,3990.67 V3987.67L2427,3986.67 V3982.67L2428,3980.67 V3979.67L2429,3977.67 V3976.67L2430,3975.67 2431,3973.67 V3972.67L2432,3971.67 2433,3984.67 V3987.67L2434,3988.67 2435,3990.67 H2436L2437,3991.67 2438,3992.67 H2440" />
          <path 
            id="path2618" 
            style="fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:none" 
            d="M2453,3976.67V3977.67L2452,3978.67 V3981.67L2451,3995.67 2450,3994.67 2449,3993.67 V3992.67L2448,3991.67 V3981.67L2449,3980.67 2450,3979.67 V3978.67L2451,3977.67 2452,3976.67 2453,3975.67 " />
            <path 
              id="path2620" 
              style="fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:none" 
              d="M2477,3994.67L2476,3995.67 2475,3996.67 H2473L2472,3997.67 H2471L2469,3998.67 H2459L2458,3997.67 H2456L2455,3996.67 2454,3995.67 H2453L2454,3981.67 V3986.67L2455,3987.67 2456,3988.67 V3988.67L2457,3989.67 2458,3990.67 H2467L2468,3989.67 H2469L2471,3988.67 2472,3987.67 2473,3986.67 V3984.67L2474,3983.67 V3980.67" />
              <path 
                id="path2622" 
                style="fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:none" 
                d="M2482,3982.67V3985.67L2481,3987.67 V3988.67L2480,3990.67 V3991.67L2479,3992.67 2478,3993.67 2477,3994.67 V3990.67L2476,3989.67 2475,3988.67 2474,3987.67 H2473L2472,3986.67 2471,3985.67 H2462L2460,3986.67 H2459L2458,3987.67 2457,3988.67 2456,3989.67 V3983.67H2449L2448,3984.67 H2446V3984.67L2444,3985.67 H2442L2441,3986.67 2440,3987.67 H2439L2438,3988.67 2437,3989.67 V3990.67L2436,3992.67 V3995.67L2435,3982.67 2436,3981.67 H2437L2439,3980.67 2440,3979.67 H2442V3979.67L2443,3978.67 H2446L2447,3977.67 H2453L2455,3976.67 H2459L2461,3977.67 H2467L2468,3978.67 H2471L2472,3979.67 H2474L2475,3980.67 2476,3981.67 2477,3982.67 2478,3983.67 V3985.67L2479,3986.67 V3988.67L2480,3989.67 V3991.67" />
      </g></svg>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get Inkscape to use absolute path commands by changing the SVG Output preferences.

Edit -> Preferences -> Input/Output -> SVG output -> Path string format -> Absolute

**Update**

Your paths are not matching because you are not interpreting the relative paths properly when you are converting.

If you overlay your original paths with your converted paths, you can see where you are going wrong.  I'm just including the first path in the example below.

```html
<svg
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   viewBox="2420 3960 70 40"
   height="300"
   width="700"
   xml:space="preserve"
   id="svg2436"
   version="1.1">
     
   <path
     d="m 2440,3992.67 v 6 h -3 l -1,-1 h -2 l -1,-1 -1,-1 -1,-1 -1,-1 h -1 v -1 l -1,-2 -1,-1 v -3 l -1,-1 v -4 l 1,-2 v -1 l 1,-2 v -1 l 1,-1 1,-2 v -1 l 1,-1 1,13 v 3 l 1,1 1,2 h 1 l 1,1 1,1 h 2" />

   <path 
     style="fill:red; fill-opacity:0.5"
     d="M 2440,3992.67 V 3998.67 H 2437 L 2436,3997.67 H 2434 L 2433,3996.67 2432,3995.67 2431,3994.67 H2430V3993.67L2429,3991.67 2428,3990.67 V3987.67L2427,3986.67 V3982.67L2428,3980.67 V3979.67L2429,3977.67 V3976.67L2430,3975.67 2431,3973.67 V3972.67L2432,3971.67 2433,3984.67 V3987.67L2434,3988.67 2435,3990.67 H2436L2437,3991.67 2438,3992.67 H2440" />

</svg>
```

Your first mistake is at the sixth path command, which is the `l`/`L` command with multiple pairs of coordinates.

```html
<svg viewBox="2420 3960 70 40" height="300" width="700">
     
   <path
     d="m 2440,3992.67
        v 6
        h -3
        l -1,-1
        h -2
        l -1,-1
          -1,-1
          -1,-1
          -1,-1
        h -1
        v -1 l -1,-2 -1,-1 v -3 l -1,-1 v -4 l 1,-2 v -1 l 1,-2 v -1 l 1,-1 1,-2 v -1 l 1,-1 1,13 v 3 l 1,1 1,2 h 1 l 1,1 1,1 h 2" />

   <path 
     style="fill:red; fill-opacity:0.5"
     d="M 2440,3992.67
        V 3998.67
        H 2437
        L 2436,3997.67
        H 2434
        L 2433, 3996.67
          2432, 3995.67
          2431, 3994.67
        H 2430" />

</svg>
```

The original relative path has four pairs of coordinates after the `l`. Your converted version only has three.

Time for you to do another debugging pass I think.  :)

Comment: Thanks for the tip Paul. I was asking the question to try to understand why they would render differently as the source may not always be Inkscape

Comment: It will be because you haven't interpreted the relative coordinates correctly.  Post your converter code if you want us to take a look at it.

Comment: Thank you Paul, it was the missing pair that was the issue. Don't know how many times I looked at the output looking for the difference!! Thanks for pointing out the obvious, I'll get my glasses checked! Cheers

Comment: @PaulLeBeau: The most simple is the best. I do not want to spend time with programming (in this case) while I want to create my sketch. Thanks for the Inkscape preferences option.